# 500 internal error webhook python

Tags: python, json, http-status-code-500, dialogflow-es

I am getting 500 error when calling webhook. I am new to python. The error is coming on line         `data = json.loads(result.decode('utf-8'))`

```
from __future__ import print_function
from future.standard_library import install_aliases
install_aliases()

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import json
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = processRequest(req)

    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    print(res)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r


def processRequest(req):
    if req.get("result").get("action") != "cryptoPrice":
        return {}
    baseurl = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
    result = urlopen(baseurl).read()
#     print(result)
    data = json.loads(result.decode('utf-8'))
    res = makeWebhookResult()
    return res


def makeWebhookResult():
#     price = data.get('buy')
#     if price is None:
#         return {}

#     print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))

    speech =  "bitcoin price is "+ result;

    print("Response:")
    print(speech)

    return {
        "speech": speech,
        "displayText": speech,
        # "data": data,
        # "contextOut": [],
        "source": "apiai-weather-webhook-sample"
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print("Starting app on port %d" % port)

    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Can someone help me please!

Comment: Have you validated that the request contains valid JSON?

Comment: I don't remember. but got it working. thanks